# Where on Big Island can I find beaches that are sheltered from waves?

Tags: beaches, hawaii

I'm currently staying in Kona and learned that most beaches around here are very much prone to strong waves, which makes it hard to casually swim around. After a lot of Googling I saw that Anaehoomalu Bay (A-bay) is a recommended beach for this and today I've confirmed that it's indeed great.

Are there other beaches sheltered from waves around Big Island? I'm able to find bits and pieces of information around the web, but not a definitive list. I'm hoping to find something closer to Kona than A-bay or at least an alternative I could explore.

Comment: There's a reason why Hawaii and Surfing are historically linked.

Comment: @CMaster yes but it's interesting that unlike other beach regions, Hawaii doesn't seem to build wave breaking structures anywhere to expand the number of waveless beaches. I.e. all the beaches in Tell Aviv are well protected from waves by artificial reefs.